# Upgrading AWS EB Platform version from 2.0.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My current platform version is: Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.0.1
Which support following NodeJS versions: 0.12.6, 0.10.39, 0.10.38, 0.10.31, 0.8.28

I am looking a way to upgrade the NodeJS version: 4.x.x which seems to be available in platform version: Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.1.0

but when I am upgrading it. it's says

[image]

How can I select the allowed version as it's not available.

Any Help,

Thanks,

P.S
1. Already tried via save / load configurations. Unable to find any option there.
2. Don't want to do setup it from the scratch for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that you have tested the changes adequately before deploying to production. After that, you can:

1. Note the name of the Platform ARN/Solution Stack you want to upgrade to.
2. Perform `eb init --region REGION_NAME` and pick the application and environment you are working on
3. Perform `eb config`. This opens your environment's configuration in an editor. Change the value of the PlatformArn to the one you noted above in step 1.
4. Also in the editor, find the option setting `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs`. Change the `NodeVersion` to 6.9.1 or one that the error message above suggests.
5. Save and quit.

After the configuration is complete:

6. Perform `eb status` to verify that your environment is using the upgraded Solution Stack.

Comment: Still useful! Was on environment 4.4.0 running Node 8.4.0, and that environment only supported 8.8.1 (code uses async/await, so cannot go back down to 7). Next available env from console was 4.8.3 but no matching node versions. Needed to `eb config` from the console, and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the existing environment to a new one, using a different platform version.
In the Actions menu, select "Clone with the latest platform".
That opens a new page where you can select from available OS/nodejs versions.

Once you are satisfied with the new environment, you can swap URLs with the old one in order to replace it. After that, you can remove the older env.

Comment: Clone also displays the same error as Configuration Validation
Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: '0.12.6' (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs', OptionName: 'NodeVersion'): Value is not one of the allowed values: [4.8.7, 4.9.1, 5.12.0, 6.14.3, 6.14.4, 7.10.1, 8.11.4, 8.12.0, 10.13.0]

Answer (score 0):

This has happened a few times before when Amazon releases new Environments and they do not include versions in common between the environments. The solution is to set value for nodejs version to an empty string which means to use the latest version. It could break your app, but you can make a clone with latest platform and switch to desired version of nodejs later. So run this command to do that:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --region "your region" --application-name "your app" --environment-name "your env" --option-settings "OptionName=NodeVersion,Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs,Value=''"
```